# Excel and Pivot, avoiding buying another 3rd part component

Tags: microsoft-excel

I hope someone can help me with this Excel problem, otherwise I'll need to buy another 3rd part control to handle the Pivot problem we've encountered. I know it's somewhat off-topic, but hopefully someone can/will help.

We have raw data that includes the following type of data:

```
ID      Date         Type
1       11.05.2009    0
2       12.05.2009    0
3       13.05.2009    1
4       14.05.2009    0
5       15.05.2009    0
```

As you can see, those five rows are from the same week.

We've organized the pivot data so that it groups by week, and we'd like to configure either a formula, calculated field, or whatnot to calculate that 1 out of 5 rows has a 1.

In other words, since there is 1 1'er, and 5 in total, we'd like to have a field that says "20%".

However, we can't figure out how to trick Excel to count the number of rows that went into a pivot cell, and sum the same rows, and thus calculate SUM/COUNT.

It seems our calculated field is done pr. row, and thus useless to us.

Basically, we'd like this:

```
      Percentage
Week
 19       0%
 20      20%     <-- this is the week from the data above
 21       0%
```

Adding a calculated field that has this formula:

```
SUM(Type)/COUNT(Type)
```

does not produce the right data, we're just getting a 0 or 1 pr. row, basically it looks like Excel does this:

```
ID      Date         Type     (Calc)
1       11.05.2009    0         0    (0/1)
2       12.05.2009    0         0    (0/1)
3       13.05.2009    1         1    (1/1)
4       14.05.2009    0         0    (0/1)
5       15.05.2009    0         0    (0/1)
```

Does anyone understand my problem? Does anyone have any hints?

It seems DevExpress Pivot control handles this, but we'd like to avoid this for the time being, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a 'Helper' column to your data titled **Count**.  Enter the number **1** into the **Count** column cells for each row of data you have.

```
ID      Date         Type   Count
1       11.05.2009    0      1
2       12.05.2009    0      1
3       13.05.2009    1      1
4       14.05.2009    0      1
5       15.05.2009    0      1
```

Create the pivot table and insert a calculated field with the formula of **=Type/Count**

In the pivot table format the calculated field as a percentage.

Based on you sample data you should get this:

```
Week   Percentage
 20      20%
```

Comment: I'll test this tomorrow when I'm back at the office.

Comment: Thank you, that worked splendidly. I guess we tried to overcomplicate things by trying to do the SUM/COUNT part ourselves.

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to the answer above.  Use the WEEKNUM function in the last column.  That will allow you to group weekly data together.

Comment: We already have that, I simplified the problem data, perhaps too much.